# Spring Data Querying DateTime with only Date

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have this Data Model

```
public class CustomerModel{

  @Column
  @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
  private DateTime membershipDate;
  //Other properties and getters
}
```

And the following repo

```
public interface CustomerRepo  extends Repository<CustomerModel, Long>{}
```

What I want to do is. Retrieve all users  on a given date eg(Members that Joined in August 1 2013) however the problem is that on my DB the membershipDate has a time with it. how can I ignore the time and retrieve all users on a given date?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately with JodaTime the only way around this is using the `Between` keyword and use two `DateTime` instances making up the day.

```
interface CustomerRepo extends Repository<CustomerModel, Long>{

  List<CustomerModel> findByMemberShipDateBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);
}
```

If your domain model used Java `Date`s internally you could've used this style:

```
interface CustomerRepo extends Repository<CustomerModel, Long>{

  List<CustomerModel> findByMemberShipDate(@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date date);
}
```

Not the `@Temporal` annotation is a custom Spring Data JPA one as the plain JPA one is currently not allowed on parameters. The reason that this only works with Java `Date`s unfortunately is a limitation of the current JPAPIs. The `setParameter(…)` method on `Query` only takes a `TemporalType` for parameters of type `Date`. We could try converting the JodaTime objects on parameter binding but I guess the persistence providers will reject that due to the type mismatch then (`Date` VS. `DateTime`).

Comment: In v1.6.2 of spring-data this annotation only supports parameters of type java.util.Date.  As such, this solution does not currently work for comparing DateTime objects.  Current javadocs located [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Temporal.html).

Comment: @yurodivuie - That's a great catch. Thanks for the pointer. I updated the answer to provide an alternative solution for JodaTime and outlining why this currently only works with Java `Date` types.

Comment: What about Java 8 ZonedDateTime in the entity and LocalDate as search parameter?

Comment: Does the stream bring the result back into memory or hold a cursor open.  I ask because of querying large result sets then mapping. Thanks!

Comment: The implementations available so far are using a cursor. I suggest to open a new question in case you want to know details as we're sort of side-tracking the current one here.

Answer (score 5):

You can do some workaround: create DateTime dayBegin and DateTime dayEnd which are e.g. 2013-07-04 00:00:00 and 2013-07-04 23:59:59 and fetch needed objects by query:

```
List<CustomerModel> findByMembershipBetween(DateTime dayBegin, DateTime dayEnd);
```

Answer (score 3):

jODA and spring & JPA actually good friends, just take alook at :

http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/04/06/spring-boot-using-joda-time-on-jpa-entity-with-hibernate/

enjoy