# Can't convert joda DateTime to Json

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jodatime, couchbase

In my spring boot project, I have an Entity with

`@Field
private org.joda.time.DateTime date;`

In my CouchbaseRepository, I make this query:

`@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE email= $1 AND date=$2")
    List<Week> findByEmailAndDate(String email, DateTime date);`

When I run my project, I get this error:

`There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unsupported type for JsonArray: class org.joda.time.DateTime`

I tried to switch to java.util.Date instead, but I got the same problem. I don't know if this is a spring issue or a couchbase one.

I should also mention that the date is stored in my couchbase documents as a timestamp:
 1499641200000.

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Comment: suppose you need to use `TemporalType.DATE`. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082276/spring-data-querying-datetime-with-only-date) may be helpful.