# How to perform a query using Spring Data, by a date field list by ignoring the time part

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data

I need to perform a query on a table using a date field, but ignoring the time portion. The complicating factor is that I need, in a single query, to pass a list of dates, as if I were using an IN clause

Comment: you can use trunc() to ignor time portion and more over add some sample data to the question!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082276/spring-data-querying-datetime-with-only-date

Comment: like nikhil say trunc() will do the job, but if your table have lots of rows then you probably need function base index with trunc(your_date), or query will be slow.