# Spring Boot Query on Date field without time

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have an entity with a Date field with type of `java.util.Date`, and this field in oracle db has the `timestamp` type.

the problem is that when i use the repository to find by given specs, it returns nothing for the given date.

It only happens when i want the exact ***equal*** date. it works fine with `greaterThen` and `lessThen` and that's because the time of the saved records are different.

how could I ignore the time of records and fetch them only for the given date?

Thanks a million

Comment: Between ddMMyy 00:00:00 and ddMMyy 23:59:59?

Comment: you are right, but i'm looking for other solutions. there might be a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the data was saved with the time best way was to do it with `between` condition from ***00:00*** to ***23:59*** in that day. special thanks to this link :

[Spring Data Querying DateTime with only Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082276/spring-data-querying-datetime-with-only-date)

but i solved the problem by creating a view from that table and removing the time from the date in oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at  @Temporal @JsonFormat annotations. [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time)

Sample usage;

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MMdd'T'HH:mm:ss")
protected Date lastUpdate;
```

Comment: Note that Spring's [`@Temporal`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Temporal.html) can only be used with `java.util.Date`. The new Java 8 Time classes don't need the annotation anymore.